# Specifying parameters for a PHP sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to specify a raw username/password into an SQL query with PHP:

```
function doRegister($username, $password) {
    $db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME) or die('error');
    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $username";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $msg = 'Username already taken';
    } else {
        $register = "INSERT INTO users(username, password)" .
                    "VALUES($username, SHA($password))";

        //error happens here
        $db->query($register) or die('error registering your account');


        $msg = "Register successful";
    }
    $db->close();
    echo $msg;
}
```

I am getting an error at `$db->query($register)`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: paste the results of mysql command `show users`; also what mysql error do you get, specifically?

Comment: **WARNING** your code may be susceptible to sql injection!

Comment: @DanielA.White - _MAY_ be?  I'd consider that _actually_ susceptible, even if the input parms are (currently) being escaped in the calling method - There's too much of a possibility of a maintainer assuming things are safe elsewhere.  Something like this (sepecially like this) should of course use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not surrounded your `$username` or `$password` in quotes, so when passing an integer it works correctly but won't accept a string:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
//----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^

$register = "INSERT INTO users(username, password)" .
                    "VALUES('$username', SHA('$password'))";
//-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Please be certain that you have properly escaped these values with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

These columns should really not be type `TEXT`. They ought to be `VARCHAR()`. Perhaps your `VARCHAR()` attempt failed because you were missing the length parameter, as in `VARCHAR(32)` for max 32 characters.

Comment: Make sure to also quote `$username` in `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $username`.

Comment: @Rocket Good catch, added above.

Comment: Actually i didn't miss the length parameter but i thought the problem is with the VARCHAR itself so i moved to TEXT, but you were right about the quotes, problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
       function doRegister($username, $password) {
        $db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME) or die('error');
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
        $result = $db->query($query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $msg = 'Username already taken';
        } else {
            $register = "INSERT INTO users(username, password)" .
                    "VALUES('$username', SHA('$password'))";
            $db->query($register) or die('error registering your account');
            $msg = "Register successful";
        }
        $db->close();
        echo $msg;
    }
```

Comment: You should also quote `$username` in `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $username`.